# Using Power Shell to Create a Spread Sheet and rename tabs

Tags: excel, powershell

I am trying to create several tabs using power shell in a new work sheet.  However I am having issues naming the tabs that I am creating.  Not sure where I am going wrong.

```
#Creates Excel application
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application

#Makes Excel Visable
$excel.Application.Visible = $true
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

#Creates Excel workBook
$book = $excel.Workbooks.Add()

#Names Sheet 1
$sheet = $book.Worksheets.Item(1)
$sheet.name = 'Recipes'

#Create Sheet 2
$excel.worksheets.add()
 
$sheet2 = $book.Worksheets.Item(2)
$sheet2.name = 'Raw Ingridents'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
#Names Sheet 1
$sheet = $book.Worksheets.Item(1)
$sheet.name = 'Recipes'

#Create Sheet 2
$sheet2 = $book.Worksheets.Add()
$sheet2.name = 'Raw Ingridents'
```

If you want to position sheet 2 after sheet 1, you can perhaps do:

```
$sheet2 = $book.Worksheets.Add([Type]::Missing, $sheet)
```

Perhaps even simpler, you can change the default number of sheets added in a new workbook:

```
$excel.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 2

#Creates Excel workBook
$book = $excel.Workbooks.Add()

#Names Sheet 1
$sheet = $book.Worksheets.Item(1)
$sheet.name = 'Recipes'

#Names Sheet 2
$sheet2 = $book.Worksheets.Item(2)
$sheet2.name = 'Raw Ingridents'
```